# changing class name and sending parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change the class of `a` tag and send a parameter `i` to the `myFunction` the tag is without id or name:

```
<a class="active" onclick="myFunction('i')"></a>

<script>
    function myFunction(obj) {            

    }
</script>
```

using `this` in the function like `myFunction(this,'i')` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> using this in the function like `myFunction(this,'i')` doesn't work.

That should work, you just need to amend the function to accept the element as an argument.

However you should note that `on*` event attributes are massively outdated and should be avoided where possible. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a.active')).forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.dataset.foo);
  }); 
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="active" data-foo="i">One</a>
<a href="#" class="active" data-foo="n">Two</a>
<a href="#" class="active" data-foo="x">Three</a>
```

**Update**:
You mentioned in the comments that you're going to use jQuery AJAX, so you can simplify above with jQuery:

```js
$('a.active').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).data('foo'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="active" data-foo="i">One</a>
<a href="#" class="active" data-foo="n">Two</a>
<a href="#" class="active" data-foo="x">Three</a>
```

Comment: is this the only way can I use? if I don't want to add data-foo what can I do?  is it necessary? I think if I want to change or use your answer to JqueryAjax it will be complicated.

Comment: It is necessary, otherwise your HTML is invalid which can lead to other issues. The pattern I outline above does not hinder AJAX use at all - if anything it makes it easier. If you're going to use jQuery for it's AJAX features then you can simplify the above anyway. I'll update it with a jQuery version.

Comment: I've tested your answer but I can't change the active class to another one or remove it how you can do it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/addclass, http://api.jquery.com/removeclass or http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass

Comment: Are onEvent Attributes only outdated or also deprecated? Cant find the later confirmation.

Comment: Only outdated. They cannot really be deprecated as so many legacy sites use them, and there are some legitimate cases where they are required, however in general practice they should be avoided. They are a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a reference to an HTML element by putting this is the function. Then you can use the element reference to do stuff to it without needing a id or name attribute.

someOtherClass is an assumed variable that contains the name of the class you want to add. Change it to whatever class or variable you want to use.

```
<a class="active" onclick="myFunction(this, 'i')"></a>

<script>
    function myFunction(obj, param2) {            
       $(obj).removeClass("active");
       $(obj).addClass(someOtherClass);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you please add some explanation to your answer, code only answers are not very helpful. thank you!

Comment: Description added. This does work. Something on your page must be interfering. Please post a more complete example.

Comment: yeah, before I posted my question I had tested some codes like yours but it doesn't work now I've created an empty one and it works!! I don't know what is wrong with my project!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
function myFunction(obj) {           
    var data = obj.attr("data-param");
    obj.removeClass("active");
    alert(data);
}


$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".test").on("click", function(){
      myFunction($(this))
  });
});

<a class="test active" href="javascript:void(0);" data-param="i">test</a>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/u81g6qk4/10/

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you do not want to use Jquery

```
<a class="active" onclick="myFunction(this, 'i')">Click Me</a>

<script>    
  function myFunction(element, str) {
      console.log(str);
    element.setAttribute('class', 'clicked');
  }
</script>
```